# ffmpeg and libaom compilation failed "unable to open include file `third_party/x86inc/x86inc.asm"

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to build ffmpeg using this guide:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

the problem is when i try to compile libaom using the following commands:

```
cd ~/ffmpeg_sources && \
git -C aom pull 2> /dev/null || git clone --depth 1 https://aomedia.googlesource.com/aom && \
mkdir -p aom_build && \
cd aom_build && \
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" -DENABLE_TESTS=OFF -DENABLE_NASM=on ../aom && \
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" make && \
make install
```

i get the following error:

```
/root/ffmpeg_sources/aom/aom_dsp/x86/sad4d_sse2.asm:14: fatal: unable to open include file `third_party/x86inc/x86inc.asm'
CMakeFiles/aom_dsp_encoder_sse2.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/aom_dsp_encoder_sse2.dir/aom_dsp/x86/sad4d_sse2.asm.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/aom_dsp_encoder_sse2.dir/aom_dsp/x86/sad4d_sse2.asm.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:842: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/aom_dsp_encoder_sse2.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/aom_dsp_encoder_sse2.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Is there any fix for this issue ?